# pyspark unable load pipelineModel

Tags: python, pyspark

I met a problem,  unable to load `PipelineModel`
I test my model in practice environment, but unable to apply this model and code on production environment

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 228, in <module>
    main(xdr_input_file,model_file,xdr_output_file)
  File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 215, in main
    xdr_df_predict = xdr_predict(xdr_df,model_file)
  File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 193, in xdr_predict
    loadmodel = PipelineModel.load(model_input_path)
  File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 257, in load
  File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 197, in load
  File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel but found class name pyspark.ml.pipeline.PipelineModel'
21/12/01 12:01:06 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Please share the code as well that is throwing this error

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the used pipeline-metadata as mentioned in the exception.

Comment: my whole code is big, so i just share the part which cause this issue,

Comment: it's the version of spark cause this issue? 
i foud official docutment :a model import/export functionality was added to the Pipeline API. As of Spark 2.3, the DataFrame-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all the help.I am a intern in bigdata industry.This is my first time to post in stackoverflow,i am sorry to post in unreguired method.

```
Finally,i sovled this problem to adjust my code from spark2.4 to spark2.2.
```

Here is details about this tracesback:
I test my code in test environment under the version of spark2.4 and python3.7; i meet error when i deploy it in product environment under the version of spark2.2 and python3.7.

I train model under product envirenment, this si Model generate error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/train/model_generate.py", line 331, in 
> main(xdr_file_path,jingfeng_file_path,save_model_path)
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/train/model_generate.py", line 318, in main
> tvs_piplineModel, gbdt_bestModel = generate_model(label_col, xdr_75109_String_title, union_df, save_model_path)
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/train/model_generate.py", line 310, in generate_model
> tvs_piplineModel.save(save_model_path)
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 217, in save
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 212, in write
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 100, in **init**
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py", line 249, in _to_java
> AttributeError: 'TrainValidationSplitModel' object has no attribute '_to_java'

when i skip model generate to model predict in model which i trained in test envirenment,this is Model predict error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 228, in 
> main(xdr_input_file,model_file,xdr_output_file)
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 215, in main
> xdr_df_predict = xdr_predict(xdr_df,model_file)
> File "/home/fwfx_yaofei/telbd-yjy/src/ml/complain_user_it/predict/model_predict.py", line 193, in xdr_predict
> loadmodel = PipelineModel.load(model_input_path)
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 257, in load
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 197, in load
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
> File "/usr/bch/1.5.0/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: Error loading metadata: Expected class name org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel but found class name pyspark.ml.pipeline.PipelineModel'

I check official document it explains ML persistence:[version changes of ML persistence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBe4y.png)
So the error might casused by the vision of spark.

I ignore the "TrainValidationSplitModel" function which mention in first traceback,and it does work.My code run successfully.
[Success run screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBe4y.png)

Conclusion, my code aim to deploy a machine-learning classificaiton model in product environment. So i import pyspark.ml.gbdt to process dataframe. But i ignore the vision of test and product envirenoment.Thanks for all the help,this is the experience of an chinese intern.Forgive my pool expressive ability.